# is java hashcode and equals example of strategy pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

If we look from HashMap point of view the variable step is calculation of hashCode and equals.
Using hashCode and equals methods HashMap can vary the algorithm to implement hashing.
What it can't vary is the strategy to calculate hashCode and euals for objects of a given type T.
Based on above argument I think it doesn't fit into definition of strategy pattern.

Am I correct?

Comment: I suppose it depends on where you get the definition for "strategy pattern".

Comment: Polymorphism and the Strategy pattern are not the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way it's implemented is not a strategy pattern. If it looked more like:

```
class HashMap {
    private final HashingStrategy strategy;

    private int computeHash(object) {
       return strategy.hash(object);
    }
}
```

Then it would be a strategy pattern. Instead, it's more like:

```
class HashMap {
    private int computeHash(object) {
        return object.hashCode();
    }
}
```

To get the hashcode of an object, the hashmap asks the object for its hashcode, it doesn't decide how to compute it. The strategy pattern is when you can plug in various algorithms to do a particular step, this is more delegating responsibility to the object.

Comment: Hmm, looks like delegation pattern... but I'm also lacking the 'term' here

Comment: The `Comparator<T>` pattern that can be used in many Java data structures is a strategy, though. Not sure why they stopped at that and did not create a `Hash<T>` strategy like C++ has.

Answer (score 1):

[Strategy Pattern - Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

If you compare your example in context of strategy pattern you will find:

- **Client is HashMap,**
- **Context is Object, and**
- **Strategies are hashCode()
  and equals() methods.**

Now if you see here strategies and context are tightly coupled, and for strategy pattern your context and strategy should be decoupled from each other, so that you can have flexibility of switching strategies for given context without changing client code.